# Выгрузка на сайт через cmd+ win7

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте, проблема такая: Пробую загрузить на сайт картинки+ два файла выгрузки в *.xml, на другом компьютере возникли проблемы.
Два файла скрипта: 
export.bat

```
@echo %time% 
ftp -i -n -s:D:\5\test\data.txt
pause
```

data.txt

```
open loretta.timeweb.ru
USER *** ***
binary
cd /system/storage/cache/exchange1c
mput C:\d\1Cv77\obmen_s_saytom*.xml
cd /image/catalog/c1
mput C:\d\1Cv77\VideoBase\Pictures*
BY
```

Ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точнее их две, одна 500 PORT/EPRT, Вторая Ошибка при открытии локального файла

Comment: Этот скрипт в принципе когда-либо работал ?

Comment: На моем ноуте работает, сканирует выгружает на сайт через ftp Все. Ну кроме если есть русские символы в названиях